# Backdrop blur filter works in chrome but in webview doesn’t

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an Android 7 phone with Chrome 77 installed there. When I check my site for backdrop filter feature through chrome it works. But when I run it from my own app with webview all works except backdrop blur filter. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 0):

backdrop-filter need Android System WebView version 76.
You can check your Android System WebView version in developer settings or goto

```
settings -> apps -> Android System WebView
```

you can update WebView in playstore [Android WebView System](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview)

Comment: It was a while ago, but as far as I remember WebView version higher 76